# Absence of Return Path, SPF and DKIM Header tags for a gmail message taken from Inbox

Tags: gmail, spf, dkim, return-path

In general, when an email is sent from one gmail account to another gmail account, and when we extract the full headers of the gmail taken from the recipients inbox, what does it mean when the header fields such as Return-Path, SPF and DKIM are NOT PRESENT in the header section?

1. Would all emails taken from Inbox mandatorily have the header tags such as Return-Path,Received-SPF and DKIM-Signature?
2. If the header tags such as Return-Path, Received-SPF and DKIM-Signature are not present for an email taken from recipient's Inbox, are those Emails considered valid or are they fabricated?

For Example: Below is the complete sample of header claimed to be the so-called full headers extracted from Gmail Inbox.

```
Delivered-To: john.delta@gmail.com
Received: by 10.90.54.9 with SMTP id c9cs539846aga; Sat, 25 Jul 2009 14:36:53 -0700 (PDT)
 MIME-Version 1.0
Received: by 10.151.100.13 with SMTP id c13mr8088064ybm.198.1248557813857; Sat, 25 Jul 2009 14:36:53 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2009 14:36:53 -0700
Message-ID: <da0ae3040907251436y49e84714t276c030c337a94cc@mail.gmail.com>
From: May Flower <may.flower@gmail.com>
To: john.delta@gmail.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=00151750dd34f9fd5a046f8e84f4

--00151750dd34f9fd5a046f8e84f4
```

In the above extract, the Return-Path, Received-SPF, DKIM-Signature tags are not available for assessing whether the email is actually genuine.

Any response from the google team is highly appreciated.

Thank you,
Priya

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Return-Path is added by gmail when it receives a message via SMTP - it is possible you could upload a message via IMAP that lacks this header. There are no such headers as SPF or DKIM, though the status of those checks does appear in other headers - is that what you mean? Can you post examples?

Comment: Posted necessary example of the header. Please let me know if the full header from Inbox is tampered or not?

Comment: That does look strange. It's missing many of the headers I expect to see in a typical message received in gmail. It's missing `Received-SPF`, `Return-Path`, `Authentication-Results` and others. I'd suggest changing your password and contacting google support.